# file.exe error when compiling dynamic matrix

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, matrix

I'm trying to make a dynamic matrix using classes. I'we made this code. Checked with other codes and it seems to be right. I get get no error messages when compiling, except for the file.exe error in the middle of the program when running this part of the code. It says file.exe has stopped working.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this code?

**header file**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class Matrix {
    unsigned int nRows, nColumns;
    double **board;
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(unsigned int nRows, unsigned int nColumns);
    ~Matrix();
};
```

**.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"
using namespace std;

Matrix::Matrix()
: nRows(0)
, nColumns(0)
, board(nullptr) 
{}
Matrix::Matrix(unsigned int nRows, unsigned int nColumns)
: nRows(nRows)
, nColumns(nColumns)
, board(nullptr)
{   

    board = new double*[nRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; ++i)
    {
    board[i] = new double[nColumns];
    }


    for (int i =0; i<nRows; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<nColumns; ++j)
        {
            board[i][j]=0.0;
        }
    }
}
Matrix::~Matrix() 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < nRows; ++i){
  delete [] board[i];
  delete [] board;
  board = 0;

  }
}
```

**main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"

int main(){
Matrix A = Matrix(5,5);
}
```

I'm running Visual Studios 2010

EDIT: 
I've debugged and the problem seems to be in both the default constructor and the the constructor I'm trying to use. At both line 13 and line 17 in .cpp, it tries to access this line:
`retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock);` in free.c

debugger states
: Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file 0xC0000005
:Access violation reading location 0x00000004

Comment: The code you provide is not a ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), nor did you even identify *which line crashed*.  You need to give the right amount of code to reproduce the problem with nothing extra included.  Does this have to do with it being in a Matrix class?  Can you just write a main routine which initializes the board and get the same problem, or does the problem emerge only when you make a class?

Comment: Debug this code in visual studio line by line and find out what line crashes it.

Comment: I'm quite new to both programming and stackoverflow, so thx for letting me know. I've isolated the program now, and given all essential code. I have to get to work, but I will try to debug the code line by line first thing when I get home, and maybe that gives a clue. Thnx anyway for taking the time.

Comment: _"It says file.exe has stopped working"_ That's when you load up your debugger mate

Comment: I've debugged and the problem seems to be in both the default constructor and the the constructor I'm trying to use. 

At both line 13 and line 17 in .cpp, it tries to access this line: 

retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock); in free.c 

debugger states: Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a copy of a Matrix and you don't have a valid copy constructor. Change your code to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"

int main(){
   Matrix A(5,5);
   return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a copy constructor:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& other) : 
    Matrix(other.nRows, other.nColumns)
{
    for (int i =0; i<nRows; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<nColumns; ++j)
        {
            board[i][j]=other.board[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

The approach you're taking is very 'C' like though. If I was implementing a matrix class, I would use standard c++ containers, probably array or vector, depending on the circumstances.

This is a working implementation of a matrix. I didn't really think it through or test and there are probably a million other implementations online which are better:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Matrix {
public:
   Matrix() : nRows(0), nColumns(0), maxSize(0) {}
   Matrix(size_t r, size_t c) : 
      nRows(r), nColumns(c), cont(r*c, 0), maxSize(r*c)
   {      
   }

   Matrix(const Matrix& other) : 
      nRows(other.nRows), 
      nColumns(other.nColumns),
      cont(other.cont.begin(), other.cont.end())
   {
   }

   void grow(size_t r, size_t c) {
      vector<double> growth(r*c, 0);
      for (size_t i=0; i<nRows; ++i) {
         for (size_t j=0; j<nColumns; ++j) {
            size_t indexNew = convertToIndex(j, i, c, r*c);
            size_t indexOld = convertToIndex(j, i);
            growth[indexNew] = cont[indexOld];
         }
      }
      nRows = r;
      nColumns = c;
      maxSize = r * c;
      cont = growth;
   }

   double get(size_t row_i, size_t col_i) const {
      return cont[convertToIndex(col_i, row_i)];
   }

   void set(size_t row_i, size_t col_i, double val) {
      cont[convertToIndex(col_i, row_i)] = val;
   }

   void printHeader() const {
      for (size_t col = 0; col < nColumns; ++col) {
         size_t width = 5;
         if (col == 0) { width = 10; }
         cout << setw(width) << col + 1;
      }
      cout << endl;
   }

   void printRow(size_t r) const {
      cout << fixed << setprecision(1);
      for (size_t col = 0; col < nColumns; ++col) {
         double d = get(r, col);
         cout << setw(5) << d;
      }
   }

   void print() const {
      if (nRows == 0 || nColumns == 0) { return; }
      printHeader();
      for (size_t row = 0; row< nRows; ++row) {
          cout << setw(5) << row + 1;
          printRow(row);
          cout << endl;
      }
   }

private:
   size_t maxSize;
   size_t nRows;
   size_t nColumns;
   vector<double> cont;

   static inline size_t convertToIndex(
      size_t col_i, size_t row_i, size_t numCols, size_t maxSize) {
      size_t index = row_i* numCols + col_i;
      if (index >= maxSize) { 
         throw out_of_range("calculated index past the end of the vector");
      }
      return index;
   }

   inline size_t convertToIndex(size_t col_i, size_t row_i) const {
      return convertToIndex(col_i, row_i, nColumns, maxSize);
   }
};

int main() {
   try {
      Matrix m(3,3);
      for (size_t i=0; i<3; ++i) {
          m.set(i,i, 1.0);
      }

      Matrix b(m);
      b.grow(5, 7);
      b.print();
   }
   catch (const exception& exp) {
      cerr << "EXCEPTION: " << exp.what() << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems to be crashing using the first code you wrote as well. I've debugged and the problem seems to be in both the default constructor and the the constructor I'm trying to use. 

at both line 13 and line 17 it tries to access this line: 
retval = HeapFree(_crtheap, 0, pBlock);
in free.c

debugger states: 
Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004. 

I'd love to see an example of how you would have solved it !

Comment: Added my implementation.